# how to pass a field contains commas and double quotes both in csv file

Tags: csv

My csv file contains 2 fields :1. Common Set and second is ["028-51YYSH89","029-5201KSAL97"]

How can I pass second value in csv file that it should consider as only one field

Currently getting output as Common Set, ["028-51YYSH89"

Please suggest.

Comment: Doesn't ["028-51YYSH89, 029-5201KSAL97"] work? you want the second field to contain "028-51YYSH89, 029-5201KSAL97" right?

Comment: where do you want to pass it? provide some more information, so people can help you.

Comment: Second field is  ["028-51YYSH89","029-5201KSAL97"]

Comment: I am passing this csv data into body data part of Http request

Comment: _“I am passing this csv data into body data part of Http request”_ – how? What server-side language are you using? Have you checked if it does not provide a method to _properly_ generate CSV data already?

Comment: Actulally I am using jmeter to generate http request and passing all necessary parameters through csv file which is required for request.

Answer (score 0):

```
["028-51YYSH89","029-5201KSAL97"]
```

You need to quote this field, and escape the quotes inside the field with an extra quote:

```
"[""028-51YYSH89"",""029-5201KSAL97""]"
```